# Java Webstart - Putting server IP in jnlp file

Tags: java, java-web-start

Is there a way to use a variable in a java webstart JNLP file so that the application that is sent to a client will have the server IP address?

My application needs to open a socket back to the server to fetch non-jar configuration files (which I am currently able to do via a hardcoded server address). I'm trying to see if there is a way to get the IP dynamically. Thanks for any help!

Comment: FYI, WebStart has been removed in Java 11. If you're developing a new application, I would choose something else, or you'll just have to make changes later on when you come to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks Mike. We are aware. It's a stop gap until a revised non-java application can be developed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are few people willing to answer webstart questions, you can create variables via the JNLP file that are accessible from the resulting Java application:

Put these inside the resources tags in the JNLP file:

```
<property name="jnlp.serverip" value="192.168.0.50"/>
<property name="jnlp.serverport" value="8080"/>
```

Note they MUST each start with "jnlp.". They can be accessed within the webstart app via

```
System.getProperty("jnlp.serverip");
```